# Animacion en items de un recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview, animación

Estoy intentando darle animación a los items de un recyclerview y quiero hacer algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo hago actualmente para animar los item del recyclerview es lo siguiente:

```
 final Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.prueba);
    viewholder.relativelayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            vh.rl.startAnimation(animation);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Al hacer eso el layout que hay en ese item en concreto se mueve a la derecha pero tengo el problema de que si hago un poco de scroll o clickeo otro item, el item anterior que realizó la animación sigue estando a la derecha y no vuelve a su estado actual. Solamente vuelve a su estado actual si el recyclerview vuelve a cargar el item.

¿Alguna solución para eso?

También he estado mirando el ItemAnimator pero no me queda muy claro =/

Comment: Creo que necesitas crear la animacion de cierre (si es que no las has creado ya). Y cada ves que selecciones un item, marcarlo o guardar una referencia del mismo. En el reciclerView debes poner un listener para el scroll, y cuando se detone el listener, que verifique si hay un elemento marcado y ejecutar la animación de cierre. Igualmente cuando selecciones otro item, que verifique lo mismo.

Comment: @SanderRito mmmm tengo que probarlo a ver, ahora como lo tengo hecho es manualmente, que al darle a un botón haga la animación inversa para cerrar.  Y como haría  iniciar la animación de cierre en el item anterior cuando seleccione otro item ?

Comment: Declara una variable `View viewOpened`, cuando hagas una animación de abrir, asigna ese view que se esta animando a esta variable `viewOpened = vh;` (basándome en tu código) para guardar referencia de que hay un View abierto por animación. Cuando selecciones otro item o hagas un scroll verifica que `viewOpened` sea diferente de nulo, y si es asi, manda llamar la función de animación de cierre. `if (viewOpened != null) { viewOpened.rl.startAnimation(closingAnimation); viewOpened = null; }`

Comment: No había caído yo en utilizar un View para guardar el vh, tiene buena pinta, voy a probarlo luego, Gracias!

Comment: @SanderRito lo he probado y nada... he estado debugueandolo a ver que pasaba y el viewOpened recibía bien el view del `vh.rl ` pero al hacer el : `viewOpened.startAnimation(animation_close);` la animación no se iniciaba, no tengo ni idea de por que

Comment: Podrias poner tu codigo con los cambios? asi poder analizar mejor que esta sucediendo. Gracias